# Unable to send mails from php mailer

Tags: php, email

i am using php mailer to send the mails from my applications,but the issue i have is that when i am using the local machine i am able to send the mails but when i  try to send mails from the hosting server.the mails are not going out. what might be the problem?. I tried out with ports `25,26,2525,465,587,2526,` in hosting server network solutions, but still not working.
it says `smtp:error()` unable to connect in hosting server, but not in local machine.

how can i solve this?
is there any alternative for this?

Comment: you must be doing something wrong, PHPMailer is best option available....

Answer (score 0):

check once you are properly inserting host_name in coding.
Host name will be provided by your hosting server.

Comment: Yeah i tried it... its working only on local machine but not in hosting server